# how to display datetime according to browser's timezone - React/JS

Tags: reactjs, date, timestamp

I have a React app in which i'm suppose to show last time data was updated.
I'm getting my data from DB and it looks like that - 2022-11-18T21:47:45+02:00 (string)
how do I convert this time stamp to match the user timezone?
for example In New york, US the time suppose to show this time minus 7 hrs.

I saw some answers here saying I can use new Date(2022-11-18T21:47:45+02:00).getTimezoneOffset() but that got me a result of -120 (Im located in IL) which means I need to reduce 2 hrs from the timestamp I provided. and that is not the solution i need.
I just wanna show the user the time this means in his location.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Date methods will return the Date according to the users local timezone. All you need to do is pass your ISO string with offset to the Date constructor.

```js
new Date("2022-11-18T21:47:45+02:00").toString();
// 'Fri Nov 18 2022 11:47:45 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)'
```